# Run import.class simultaneously and still being able to talk with them (put/get)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been searching and searching on Google/Stackoverflow for the problem I'm having with asyncio,multiprocessing and other stuff I've tried. And my wish is to have someone to help me setting this up.

But scenario is in .py file I want to load multiple modules with its class. And they all ends with '`mi6.CMOD()`' which is the class I've imported from '`importlib`'.

What I want for this project is how I talk with the '`multiprocessing.thread()`'. I would like you know how I can put stuff in those classes being imported.

Like if the `list['name'] = mi6.CMOD` and I want to edit the variable in the by calling `list['name'].value = 1`
And also I want to grab information from there.

My project is on GitHub and I would love to have someone helping me getting this to work. [Github:kuzeyron](https://github.com/kuzeyron/ProjectHamilton/blob/master/server.py#L52-L81).
I'm somehow new to this so kind answers are very welcomed!

Google/Stackoverflow haven't given me anything else than how to retrieve information. Not changing values and stuff like that.

Thank you for reading this!

Comment: Looks like (at least) two problems mixed into one. Dynamic class loading, thread communication. I suggest something like nanomsg or zeromq to pass values around. Just a note of warning - python is not well suited for multi threading (only one 'true python' thread can run at a time due to GIL).

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I need to find a way to do this. It is very important.

Comment: The first question you have to ask yourself is "Is the multi threaded code going to wait for IO or C extension?" If the answer is "no", multi threading will only do harm. If the answer is "yes", check some event based libraries like gevent or twisted.

Comment: @liborm it should never stop waiting for the scripts to end unless you've sent the quit code. And meanwhile I should be able to talk with the classes/scripts. Thank you for your comment! I'll do some readings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by writing in a special way with the help of `multiprocessing.manager.BaseManager`

So everything is running as it should!